# artinian subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

$B$ be a Subring of artinian ring  $A$ . Is B artinian ring always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for example the subring $\mathbb{Z}$ of the Artinian ring $\mathbb{Q}$ is not Artinian.